# 3n+1 wrong answer according to uva onlinejudge

Tags: c

I am trying to solve the "3n+1" question and submit it on uva onlinejudge but every time it says that my code gives the wrong answer and unfortunately i can't find it's problem
here is the question: [Problem 100](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=36&mosmsg=Submission+received+with+ID+18223743)

My Code:

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        int main()
        {
            unsigned long int n, m;
            int max = 0;
            scanf("%d %d", &n, &m);

            int i;
            for (i = n; i <m + 1; i++)
            {
                int ter = i;
                int counter = 1;
                while (ter != 1)
                {
                    counter++;

                    if (ter % 2 == 1) { ter = 3 * ter + 1; }

                    else
                        ter = ter / 2;

                    if (ter == 1)
                        if (counter>max) { max = counter; }
                }
            }

            printf("%d %d %d\n", n, m, max);

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: `3n+1`? Isn't it the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)? Does it work correctly on the sample inputs?

Comment: And gives the correct results every time you use it? For every kind of values you input? Have you tried some corner cases, like inputting negative number for one or both input? Zeroes? Very large numbers? `n` larger than `m` or the opposite?

Comment: I think you should start your `counter` at zero

Comment: Are you sure that `n` is always less than `m`?

Comment: And you just accept that? You don't think the "online judge" would throw in some erroneous values just to test your codes robustness? I would do that. Also, you are declaring `n` and `m` as `unsigned long`, but you ask [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) to read `signed int` values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude They are usually stating the constraints on the possible input.. But yeah, it's not a good excuse not to check it.

Comment: it doesn't work even without the unsigined

Comment: What I mean is that you should change the [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) format to actually read `unsigned long`. And add a check to see that [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) succeeded.

Comment: the posted code fails to allow for there being more than one line of input.

Comment: the posted code uses `scanf()` and `printf()`,   in comparison to simple functions that use `getchar_unlocked()` and `putchar_unlocked()` those functions in the posted code take 'forever'.  Strongly suggest searching for the short/fast functions, so as to help avoid going over the time limit.

Comment: please post (as additional text) your modified code that is still not working.  Then we could help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is clear. You are not following the instructions from the problem statement

> For any two numbers i and j you are to determine the maximum cycle
>   length over all numbers between i and j.

> The input will consist of a series of pairs of integers i and j, one
>   pair of integers per line. All integers will be less than 1,000,000
>   and greater than 0.

1. You only read one line of input and print that answer
2. You assume that `i` is less than `j`

Comment: I think the problems you mentioned is now fixed but it still says that my answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Correct Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int cycleSize(int x) {
int cycle = 1;

while (x != 1) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) { //if even
        x = x / 2;
    } else { //if odd
        x = x * 3 + 1;
    }
    ++cycle;
}
return cycle;
}

int maxCycleSizeBetween(int a, int b) {
if (a > b) { //if b > a, swap them
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
int maxCycle = 0;

for (; a <= b; a++) {
    int thisCycleSize = cycleSize(a);
    if (thisCycleSize > maxCycle) {
        maxCycle = thisCycleSize;
    }
}
return maxCycle;
}

int main() {
int a, b; //input vars

while (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) != EOF) {
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, maxCycleSizeBetween(a, b));
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now see the answer.

Comment: In the future, please don't post non-answers as answers. You have edited this into an answer, but your first version of it was not actually an answer to the question. Please read about [answer] questions here.

Comment: please, for ease of readability and understanding, consistently indent the code

Comment: I think the guy who has asked the ques can easily understand it , as it was read by him many times before asking

Comment: this answer fails when `a > b`  as the problem statement says the output must have the displayed values in the same order as the input values.

Comment: @Ed Cottrell sorry.won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

the following code implements the requirements

However, some online code contests expect a final blank line. You will need to determine those kinds of details.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    size_t n1;
    size_t m1;
    char buffer[1024];

    while( fgets( buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin ) )
    {
        if( 2 != sscanf(buffer, "%lu %lu", &n1, &m1) )
        {
            break;
        }

        size_t n = n1;
        size_t m = m1;

        if( n1 > m1 )
        { // then first number greater than second so reverse for calculations
            size_t temp = n;
            n = m;
            m = temp;
        }

        size_t maxCount = 0;
        for (size_t i = n; i <= m; i++)
        {
            size_t ter = i;
            size_t counter = 1;

            while (ter != 1)
            {
                counter++;

                if ( (ter & 0x01) == 1) 
                {  // then odd
                    ter = 3 * ter + 1; 
                }

                else
                { // else even
                    ter = ter / 2;
                }

                // for testing only
                // printf( "%lu: %lu, %lu\n", counter, i, ter );
            }

            if( maxCount < counter )
            {
                maxCount = counter;
            }
        }

        printf("%lu %lu %lu\n", n1, m1, maxCount);
    }
}
```

Note:

1. this code will exit if non numeric value entered
2. this code will exit if a EOF encountered -- this is expected
3. this code will fail if a negative number entered, however; the contest stipulation says that the numbers will be in the range 1...1000000 so no need to check for negative numbers
4. this code will exit if only one number on input line
5. this code will exit if only a `<cr>` is entered

Comment: hi,
your code it the right answer but i still can't find my code's problem(i changed it after seeing your code)

Answer (score 0):

The following function performs the requested calculation:

```
void n3plus1(int min, int max)
{
    int i, n, len, lenmax=0;

    for (i=min; i<=max; i++)
    {
        n= i; len= 1;
        while (n!=1) {
            if (n&1)
                 n= 3*n + 1;
            else n= n/2;
            len++;
        }
        if (len>lenmax) lenmax= len;
    }
    printf("Answer: %d %d %d\n", min,max,lenmax);
}
```

With the following tests:

```
void test(void)
{
    n3plus1(22, 22);
    n3plus1(1, 10);
    n3plus1(100, 200);
    n3plus1(201, 210);
    n3plus1(900, 1000);
}
```

the output is:

```
Answer: 22 22 16
Answer: 1 10 20
Answer: 100 200 125
Answer: 201 210 89
Answer: 900 1000 174
```

Note: the "*the maximum cycle length over all numbers between i and j*" in the problem statement must be interpreted as including `i` and `j`.

The code assumes `i<=j` on input. The code excludes reading the input.